# Can I add a maximum expiry date to a session cookie?

Tags: cookies

I have set a [session cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie), which doesn't have any expiry date and will therefore be deleted when the browser is closed.

Now I would like to add a maximum expiry date, meaning that

- if the browser is closed before the maximum expiry date, my cookie is deleted
- otherwise my cookie will be deleted passed the maximum expiry date

Notice that I don't want to set a "regular" expiry date because that would make my cookie [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Persistent_cookie), failing to be deleted when the browser is closed before the expiry date.

The only solution I found is to have a second, persistent, cookie, with the maximum expiry date: I manually delete my first cookie if that second one is not found (expired). Since I would like to write as little information as possible in cookies, I'd prefer if there were another way.

After @CBroe's comment, I'm adding that the cookie is generated on the client side and I don't have an associated server side session where to store a last access timestamp

**2018 update**

After starting a bounty on this question, I got a couple of answers. Thank you. As a feedback, which could possibly better clarify the purpose of my question, please notice that **I am not looking for code to set a persistent cookie or to implement the solution that I already have** (set a second persistent cookie). I was hoping for some other creative suggestions. At the moment, I could use Zeeshan's hint and set the timestamp in the value (I would append it to the actual value). That answer is therefore so far the best candidate for being awarded the bounty.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by this? (I assume you are not only setting a “session cookie” in the client-side sense, but also have a server-side session associated with it? In that case, you should store the last access timestamp into the session, and then on the next request check if the time difference is too big.)

Comment: @CBroe I do web analytics. I don't have a server side session. I do have a session cookie in the client-side sense, I'm grouping pageviews by visit based on that cookie and would like to have a maximum visit duration

Comment: That’s something you should rather handle in your processing of the data then. // Especially for analytic purposes, you’d probably want to be able to identify me as the same user again, even if I closed my browser, and then open your site seconds later again – with a session cookie, that would be problematic. So store a cookie that is valid for longer, and implement the necessary logic to “group” page views together by specific time frames in the backend.

Comment: @CBroe I already have a persistent visitor cookie. If you close the browser and open the site later again, I'd like to count 1 visitor and 2 visits. But then it gets difficult to break long visits (Someone doesn't close their browser for hours or days)

Comment: _“But then it gets difficult to break long visits (Someone doesn't close their browser for hours or days)”_ – again, I’d look at the interval between consecutive requests for that. // Are you sure implementing this yourself makes sense to begin with? Even if the “big players” like Google Analytics & co. are out of the question for privacy reasons or whatever, there’s still open source solutions such as Piwik, that you can set up and run on your own system. And a lot of thought has been given to how those tools work best already – so re-inventing the wheel might not be the wisest choice here.

Comment: @CBroe You are right, but acutally my complete scenario is more complex and too localized to be an interesting topic for SO. I'm considering to delete the question if it's not clear enough with its original requirements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102495/discussion-between-mario-trucco-and-cbroe).

Comment: @MarioTrucco with java we can use setMaxTime(int) this method to set cookies maximum expiry date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to keep cookie as session cookie you can not set expiry. 
so you can either set timestamp as cookie value or create new cookie and set value as timestamp.

```
var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime()
document.cookie = "cookiename=value;  path=/";
document.cookie = "expirycookie="+timestamp+";  path=/";
```

for only client side solution you can set interval to check cookie timestamp value. 
add below code to all your pages

```
   var interval = setInterval(function(){
         var timeStamp = getCookie('expirycookie') 
         if(!timeStamp){clearInterval(interval); return}
         var cookieDuration = 5*60*1000 //expire cookie after 5 min
         if(timeStamp < (new Date()).getTime() - cookieDuration){
           //cookie expired delete here
           document.cookie = 'cookiename=value; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
           document.cookie = 'expirycookie=value; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
          clearInterval(interval)
        }
      },1000)

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## `Cookie::setMaxAge(int)`

in Java we have to specify an expiration time, you can use the [`setMaxAge(int)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge-int-) method of `javax.servlet.http.Cookie.` It takes as a parameter the number of seconds before the cookie will expire.

For example, for a five minute expiration, we would do the following :-

```
// Create a new cookie for userID from a fictitious
// method called getUserID
Cookie cookie = new Cookie ("userID", getUserID());

// Expire the cookie in five minutes (5 * 60)
cookie.setMaxAge( 300 );
```

When the cookie is sent back to the browser, using `HttpServletResponse.addCookie(Cookie)`, it will only be returned by the browser until the expiration date occurs. If you'd prefer, you can also specify a negative value for `setMaxAge(int)`, and the cookie will expire as soon as the browser exits. Note however that not everyone will shutdown their browser, and it might be available for minutes, hours even days. Finally, specifying a value of zero will expire the cookie instantly.

Here is full Java Servlet example.

```
// Import required java libraries
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class HelloForm extends HttpServlet {

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      // Create cookies for first and last names.      
      Cookie firstName = new Cookie("first_name", request.getParameter("first_name"));
      Cookie lastName = new Cookie("last_name", request.getParameter("last_name"));

      // Set expiry date after 24 Hrs for both the cookies.
      firstName.setMaxAge(60*60*24);
      lastName.setMaxAge(60*60*24);

      // Add both the cookies in the response header.
      response.addCookie( firstName );
      response.addCookie( lastName );

      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String title = "Setting Cookies Example";
      String docType =
         "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " + "transitional//en\">\n";

      out.println(docType +
         "<html>\n" +
            "<head>
               <title>" + title + "</title>
            </head>\n" +

            "<body bgcolor = \"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
               "<h1 align = \"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
               "<ul>\n" +
                  "  <li><b>First Name</b>: "
                  + request.getParameter("first_name") + "\n" +
                  "  <li><b>Last Name</b>: "
                  + request.getParameter("last_name") + "\n" +
               "</ul>\n" +
            "</body>
         </html>"
      );
   }
}
```

And HtML file will be

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "HelloForm" method = "GET">
         First Name: <input type = "text" name = "first_name">
         <br />
         Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "last_name" />
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could add this tip: Rather than hard-code “magic numbers” such as `300`, you could make you code more self-documenting by using `TimeUnit` enum: `myCookie.setMaxAge( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds( 5 ) ) ;  // replaces `300` integer literal. `

Comment: basil bourque yes 100% agree

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem here is that this is a regular persistent cookie, and it will be still there after closing and reopening the browser (before the expiry date), hence not satisfying my requirements